# Adding User Pointer to PFObject in Swift

Tags: swift, parse-platform, pfobject, pfuser

I am using Parse SDK in Swift and trying to create a new vote Object, then save a pointer to the current user.

I get the following error - [Error]: can't add a non-pointer to a relation (Code: 111, Version: 1.7.1).

```
func createVoteObject(row: Int, quest: PFObject) {
    var vote = PFObject(className: "Votes")
    vote["user"] = PFUser.currentUser()

    vote.saveInBackgroundWithBlock {
        (success: Bool, error: NSError?) -> Void in
        if error != nil {
            println("Error saving vote object: \(error!)")
        } else {
            Do something else
        }
    }
}
```

I have no problem adding other properties.

**I get the same issue with this function**

```
func saveVoteToUserObject(vote: PFObject, quest: PFObject) {

    if let currentUser = PFUser.currentUser() {
        var userToVoteRelation = currentUser.relationForKey("votes")
        userToVoteRelation.addObject(vote)
        var userToQuestRelation = currentUser.relationForKey("votedOnQuests")
        userToQuestRelation.addObject(quest)

        currentUser.saveInBackgroundWithBlock {
            (success: Bool, error: NSError?) -> Void in
            if error != nil {
                println(error)
            } else {
                println("Successfully saved vote to User object")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: Did you refresh the user (or fetch is perhaps the current API method). And is `user` a pointer instead of a relation? Do both sets of code give exactly the same error?

Answer (score 1):

Wain inspired the fix for this.  Had to refresh the user by clearing the cache and logging back in (either using PFUser.logOut() or Reset Contents and Settings in iOS Simulator).

Any time you're trying to create a pointer, need to use the most recent version of the pointer object.  I had added some fields to the User object, which weren't being updated in the my PFUser.currentUser() instance, since it is cached.

Answer (score 0):

Confirmed. I was seeing this error using

```
newProfileImage["owner"] = PFUser.currentUser()
```

to set a pointer to the user. The following works:

```
PFUser.currentUser()?.fetch()

newProfileImage.setObject(PFUser.currentUser()!, forKey: "owner")
```